# In a in WinRT app, how do I connect using TLS1.2?

Tags: windows-runtime, tls1.2, winrt-async, stream-socket-client, servicepointmanager

I've got a Windows Store app that's a WinRT Phone/Desktop app (i.e. not a UWP app), targeting Windows 8.1 and up.

It's been on the store for several years now, but recently it stopped being able to connect with various web APIs and websites (YouTube, as well as my own site) using HTTPS.

I have a WPF version of this app as well, and this happened on that app recently as well, and to fix it I used `System.Net.ServicePointManager`.  Unfortunately, in my WinRT environment, `System.Net` doesn't include `ServicePointManager`.  In my WPF app, I did this, and it worked just fine:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate
{
    Debug.WriteLine("returning true (the ssl is valid)");
    return true;
};

// our server is using TLS 1.2
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

In doing some research around the internet, it seems that .NET 4.6 should include `ServicePointManager`, but I don't see any way to change (or even see) my version of .NET in the WinRT development environment.

I looked some more and found that a `StreamSocket` could be used to connect with TLS1.2... but that seems primarily designed to enable bluetooth communications, or communications to a web endpoint, but *only by hostname*... which is insufficient for me.  I need to connect to an actual website, not just the base-level domain.

Trying this, I did the following:

```
StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
string serverServiceName = "https";
socket.Control.KeepAlive = false;
url = "inadaydevelopment.com";
HostName serverHost = new HostName(url);
await socket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverServiceName, SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12);
text = await ReadDataFromSocket(socket);
```

I can include the code for `ReadDataFromSocket()` if necessary, but it seems to work, reading the data from the socket as expected when I point it at https://google.com.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to point the socket at anything useful.  The homepage of inadaydevelopment.com isn't what I want; I'm looking to consume a web API hosted on that server, but can't seem to find a way to do that.

Since the first parameter to the `ConnectAsync()` method is just `HostName`, the second parameter (`remoteServiceName`) must be the way to connect to the actual API or webpage I'm trying to connect to.  According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.connectasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Networking_Sockets_StreamSocket_ConnectAsync_Windows_Networking_HostName_System_String_Windows_Networking_Sockets_SocketProtectionLevel_), that is `The service name or TCP port number of the remote network destination...`  I haven't seen any example values for this parameter other than `https` and various numeric values, neither of which is going to get me to the API endpoint or webpage I'm trying to connect to.

So, with that super-long preamble out of the way, **my question boils down to this**:

Is there a way for me to use `System.Net.ServicePointManager` in my WinRT app like I do in my WPF app?  If so, how?

If not, how can I use `StreamSocket` to connect to the exact web service or webpage I want to connect to, rather than just the top-level host?

If that's not possible, by what other means can I consume web content using TLS1.2?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Windows.Web.Http` API instead of `System.Net.Http` API.

`System.Net.Http` does not support TLS1.2 but `Windows.Web.Http` does in WinRT apps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot!

Comment: I finally got a chance to circle back to this project, and your suggestion worked!  Thanks so very much!  I had a bounty open on this question for a week, but your answer came in too late.  If there's a way for me to award it to you anyway, let me know how to do that and I'll be happy to hook you up!  =)

Comment: For anyone else coming along after the fact, this is the MS doc page I used to find the specifics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0

Comment: I actually answered it when you had the bounty up, that's how I found this question.

Comment: I'm very sorry I didn't see it and award that before it expired!  Turns out I can reopen the bounty and award it to you in 23 hours.